# Internet Explorer 9 Keeps using the wrong CAB file

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, activex

I'm working on an activeX component of a web application with Visual Studio 2008 in Windows 7 and IE9. I have a method to test it so that i don't have to deploy it to the Web server to check whether it is working or not.

However, recently I noticed that IE9 has been using an unreleased version of the ActiveX component. I kept building and updating codes here and there, and apparently IE is grabbing that build version which is unreleased yet. The released version is available on the webserver, while the one i'm testing is not released yet as it is still incomplete.

Can anyone tell me how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Do your ActiveX controls share the same GUID?

Comment: I'm not too sure, I didn't change anything while doing the build so it might be using the same GUID.

Comment: Could you provide more information about this? Like how you call the ActiveX component from your web application. Do you get the component from your web server, build-in server of Visual Studio or local dll? In the meantime, please check whether you installed the incomplete control previously. You can remove the control from your IE and try again.